# How can I add a file to another file which is such as named store.dat in Java?

Tags: java, file, application-security

All data must be stored in one single persistent file name secure_store.dat.

The following command should add new files to the Secure Store realm:

`put [path_on_OS] [file_name]`

How can I do this ? 
How can I add a file that in my PC to secure.store ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind that secure_store.dat will be a zipped file then you can use standard Java handling for zipped files...

Edit:
When you add multiple files together into one single file you must store them in such a way to preserve their boundaries, if you fail to do that the two or more files will become garbled mess.

java.util.zip functionality provides all features that you seem to need,  it will create a zipped archive file with separate entries for each file that you add. It provides functionality to add/extract/remove files from the archive too.

Comment: Can you explain more detailed? 
I couldnt imagine what you said
Thank you so much again.